# How to represent a sparse array in JSON?

Tags: json, sparse-array

I've got a sparse array that I want to represent in JSON. For example:

```
  -10 => 100
   -1 => 102
    3 => 44
   12 => -87
12345 => 0
```

How can I do this? Can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can represent it as a simple object:

```
{
  "-10" : 100,
  "-1" : 102,
  "3" : 44,
  "12" : -87,
  "12345" : 0
}
```

Since it will be a simple object, you cannot iterate it the same way as an array, but you can use the [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/for...in) statement:

```
for (var key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var value = obj[key];
  }
}
```

And if you want to access an specific element by key, you can use also here the square bracket [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Member_Operators):

```
obj['-10']; // 100
```

Note that I use the [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method inside the [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/for...in) loop, this is to prevent iterating properties defined on higher levels of the prototype chain, which can cause problems and unexpected behavior... more info [here](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#forin).

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you could really iterate it as an Array in the normal way anyway, since there are negative indices. Object it is.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. JSON object members name are strings. Strings can hold any UTF-8 encoded value:

```
{
  "-10"   : 100,
  "-1"    : 102,
  "3"     : 44,
  "12"    : -87,
  "12345" : 0
}
```